# How can I find classpath for Java in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I try to debug Java code on Visual Studio Code, but I always get this error `Failed to resolve classpath: Main class '<name of mainclass here>' doesn't exist in the workspace.` I need help. How can I find mainclass or classpath for Java?

Comment: Are you using a build tool, e.g. Maven?

Comment: I use Microsoft extension for Java. But it requires a classpath in the launch.json file. So that's why I cannot debug Java code script.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the Code Runner extension? You need some kind of extension to run/debug java in vscode.

Comment: Yes, i installed the extension. It is microsoft extension for Java